# How to clear disk read cache?

Tags: windows, cache, ssd, anti-virus

For performance testing I need a way to clear all disk read caches, since rebooting takes time. Clearing the Windows managed cache [clearing OS cache](https://serverfault.com/questions/91804/how-to-clear-windows-disk-read-cache) is not enough in my case.

I want to measure performance of loading sound files in a game.

At some moment, the game loads 4080 files, each of size about 30 KB. For each file, the game calls `fopen` a few times. The last one is successful, so the `fseek`+`ftell`+`fread` are used to read the whole file, then file is `fclose`-ed.

Loading such small files incurs a lot of overhead in Windows and NTFS.
The loading is done in 12 threads on 12 logical threads, but there is a mutex on opening files,  parallelization is not helpful since most of work is serialized by the mutex. Total size of assets loaded is 4 GB, which fits into 16 GB of RAM I have.

I have two SSDs:

- **Gammix**: Gammix S11 Pro 1 TB NVMe SSD, not encrypted
- **Samsung**: Samsung 850 EVO 250 GB SATA SSD, with OS and VeraCrypt encryption

Sequence of measurements:

- machine reboot
- Gammix: **19 sec**
- Gammix: **0.95 sec**
- RamMap clear cache
- Gammix: **2.1 sec**
- Samsung: **18.7 sec**
- Samsung: **1.0 sec**
- RamMap clear cache
- Samsung: **3.17 sec**

The numbers seem rather stable.

The second run is fully cached and happens from RAM, and it takes 1 second regardless of SSD.

The third run only has OS cache cleared, so the data should be loaded from SSD, it takes 2 and 3 seconds respectively.

The first run is the truly cold scenario, and takes about 20 seconds regardless of SSD. This is the huge difference, what causes it is unknown, and no way to clear it except reboot.

Comment: Have you try to exec `sync;sync;sync` and check the result?

Comment: @RomeoNinov. I used [this code](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/259577/How-to-flush-a-storage-volumes-the-file-cache-lock) to do [FlushFileBuffers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-flushfilebuffers) on Gammix disk, ran it 3 times interleaved with RamMap clear after first game load attempt. Then second attempt takes 2.1 seconds, so it does not change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **Windows Antivirus**

---

I was fixated on the idea of cache in SSD itself, it only now decided to check the other possibilities. The obvious idea of antivirus turned out to be the right one. I used [this way to temporarily disable Windows antivirus](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/turn-off-defender-antivirus-protection-in-windows-security-99e6004f-c54c-8509-773c-a4d776b77960).

Here is another test sequence:

- machine reboot
- disable antivirus
- Gammix: **2.1 sec**
- enable antivirus
- RamMap clear cache
- Gammix: **20.5 sec**

I confirmed that:

1. Loading time is the same in two cases: after fresh boot with antivirus disabled; on repeated attempt after RamMap clear;
2. It is enough to disable antivirus and immediately reenable it back to clear its scan cache. This can be used to repeat performance testing with antivirus enabled.

**P.S.** Nothing helps more with problem solving than asking a question and visiting restroom =) Sorry.

Comment: What "game file" types are impacted by antivirus and how could they compromise an endpoint?

Comment: @GregAskew, I have no idea what is scanned and why. My issue happens on ogg/vorbis sound files. Maybe it checks for known signatures of exploits targeting popular sound players. Maybe it does not actually scan these files, but the overhead is due to the hook which checks filters.

Comment: I'm trying to think of a use case of where this could be on topic. Also I'm certain that some products don't perform similarly when disabled and require installation for a proper benchmark. Which is usually not a problem.